# Can I configure gitosis to ask for passwords and check against an Active Directory

Tags: git, active-directory, gitosis

I have successfully installed and configured gitosis on an Ubuntu server. We're currently just a few developers creating a development platform for a large organization (more than 2000 employees.)

Currently they use subversion for version control. The departments can modify their users permissions by editing and commit a single file, much like gitosis.conf. However the difference is they don't need to push public keys for their users, but use the user's domain login, since subversion is configured to check users against our AD.

Is there's a way gitosis can behave similarly:

- They edit gitosis.conf, but they don't need to add the public keys.
- How do I configure git/gitosis to ask for users password and check them agains the AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been reading some post in order to achieve this. I've been able to setup the smart git http backend, and using Apache's LDAP Auth module I've have achieve the AD integration.

Now I'm hacking gitosis hooks to generate the "Require users" for Apache and reloading the apache configuration.

Another possible way is to setup Gitorious and subscribe the ActiveMQ the use for messaging between subsystems.

Here's the list of post I've been reading:

- http://www.toofishes.net/blog/git-smart-http-transport-lighttpd/
- http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html
- http://www.openg.info/tag/steps-setup-git-http-backend-apache-windows
- http://www.openg.info/entry/authentication-git-push-http